# Splitting a date format

Tags: python, datetime

*What I want to do?* I want to print **only** the days of the specific month which is the third element of the date. 
*What I have?* I have a **function** that outputs the date but in the place of the "month number" it has the "number of days of the month", like this: 2001-11-30 00:00:00 (the third element is the days of the month) 
*What I tried?* I tried making the date into a string and outputing its third element like so date[2] .

*Libraries allowed only:  datetime*

The function I described above:

```
def last_day_of_month(date):
    if date.month == 12:
        return date.replace(day=31)
    return date.replace(month=date.month+1, day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

What I did:

```
date = str((last_day_of_month(ImportedDate)))
print (date[2])
```

The output: **0**

Can you describe me any possible solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not `date = last_day_of_month(ImportedDate).day` ?

Comment: Oh yes, it works, I never thought of that. Maybe the split method doesn't work after all in date format.Thank you @LaurentH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you this simple solution (you get an integer):

```
date = last_day_of_month(ImportedDate).day
```

You may also use slicing on your string, as follows (you get a string):

```
date = str((last_day_of_month(ImportedDate))
print(date[8:10])
```